# There is a smooth map of degree 1 from $S^1 \times S^1$ to $S^2$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have been told the statement in the title, but I don’t see how to construct such a function. An hint was to “collapse the $S^1$”, but I am not sure what that means. I should find a surjective function that is homotope to the identity, maybe?

Comment: This was asked so many times, see questions linked to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782261/degree-1-map-from-torus-to-sphere

Comment: Perhaps a more general question is easier: You can construct a degree 1 map from any compact, orientable surface to the sphere.

Comment: Do you have any hints gor the more general case? Also, I have seen the other question, but the answer given below seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $S^1\times S^1$ as a closed square with pairs of opposite
edges identified. Now identify them to a point. This represents $S^2$ as
a quotient of $S^1\times S^1$, and "most" points in $S^2$ have just one
point in their preimage, so the degree of the map (subject to orientation) is $1$.

If you like, think of the torus with two circles, going around the torus
in the two most natural ways. Collapsing these $S^1$s
to a point gives an $S^2$.

Comment: It makes sense, but collapsing things won’t give me something non smooth? The only thing that puzzles me about your approach is the smoothness

Comment: I'm sure all this can be "smoothed out" but I don't want to work out the details right now....