# Avoiding the spherical polar coordinate singularity on $S^2$ by using a double cover?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, coordinate-systems

Is it possible to avoid the spherical polar coordinate singularity on $S^2$ by taking the coordinates as they originally are on $T^2$, i.e. ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$ mod $2\pi$? How would one incorporate this in practice? The position vector to a point on a unit $S^2$ is ${\bf r} = {\bf e}_{\rho}$, where ${\bf e}_{\rho}$ is a unit vector in the direction of increasing radius. With the usual single cover, ${\bf e}_{\theta}$, where $\theta$ indicates the azimuth, becomes ambiguous at the North and South poles. How exactly is this avoided with the double cover?

Comment: double cover ? you mean the coordinate chart we use in Riemannian manifolds ?

Comment: I don't see that it is. Remember that $S^2$ is simply connected and has no connected double-cover.

Comment: @TedShifrin : what does it mean ?

Comment: Yes I am talking about coordinate charts here.

Comment: Use a second coordinate chart, namely spherical coordinates centered on the $x$-axis (instead of the $z$-axis).

Comment: Related: [Why spherical coordinates is not a covering?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307517).