# $S^1\times S^1$ to $S^2$ continuous surjective map.

Tags: general-topology

Does there exists a continuous surjective map from $S^1 \times S^1$ to $S^2$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE.  Take a look at some questions and answers and you will find that ones that get a better reception and responses are ones where the OP explains not only the context of the question, but shows their thought process and/or attempts and where they got stuck. Context is important, e.g. since this is only tagged as general topology, useful connections to algebraic topology may not be provided.

Comment: Can we please give a new contributor a chance to absorb feedback and revise before TWO downvotes?

Comment: such as projection onto a sphere that is completely inside the torus?

Comment: Welcome to (posting at) MSE! <> [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307517/why-spherical-coordinates-is-not-a-covering) is stronger than what you ask, but the diagram may help you visualize one way to get such a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $f:S^1\times S^1 \to S^2$  by  $(e^{i \theta},e^{i \phi})$ $\to$ $(\cos\theta \sin \phi,\sin \theta \cos \phi, \cos\phi)$.
The above map is continuous because it is coordinate wise continuous and surjective because it is nothing but spherical parametrization of unit sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this: view $S^1 \times S^1$ as a quotient of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (the standard picture with opposite sides of the square identified). There is a further quotient given by collapsing the entire boundary of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to a point. This further quotient is $S^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the prior answer and in the spirit of how this might be thought of by algebraic topologists:

First take the torus and pinch one factor $S^1$ to a point (this turns the bagel into a hot dog where the tip of each end is joined), which has the homotopy type of $S^1\vee S^2$.  Then collapse $S^1$ to a point, resulting in $S^2$. The sequence looks like this where each arrow is a quotient map:

$S^1\times S^1\rightarrow S^1\times S^1/S^1\times \{*\}\simeq S^1
\vee S^2\rightarrow S^2$